# How can I merge an image with a line and save both in a file?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I would like to save an image together with an overlay, which is in my case a simple line across the whole image. When I save this image it does not include my line and therefore my question how can I merge this line with my image to save BOTH in one file?!

Here my code for saving the image:

```
// Save image
var encoder1 = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder1.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)image.Source));

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.png", FileMode.Create))
encoder1.Save(stream);
```

The line is added like this:

```
grid2.Children.Add(myLine);
```

How can I merge the line with the image to save both at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this in WPF. Here it seems that you just want to draw the content of your `grid2` panel into a bitmap (of course assumed that the Image control is also a child element of `grid2`).

This could easily be done by means of a RenderTargetBitmap like this:

```
var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)grid2.ActualWidth, (int)grid2.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
bitmap.Render(grid2);

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

using (var stream = new FileStream("test.png", FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

Please note that this solution enables you to draw any kind of UI element - not just a Line - on top of the image, and save the result to file.

If you perhaps just want to load an image file, draw some simple shapes on top and save it back to file, you may consider using [WritabelBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead("myJpeg.jpg"))
{
    Image sourceImage = Image.FromStream(s);

    Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(sourceImage);
    canvas.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 5), 0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height);
    sourceImage.Save("test.jpg");
}
```

It draws a line from the tope left to bottom right of the image.

Comment: Drawing a line was not the problem but to merge the line with the image

Comment: @Norick Please also note that the solution presented here is based on WinForms APIs, not WPF. Although you would be able to execute this in a WPF application, it is not recommended to do so.